# Removing JSON Array in JSONObject based on key in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a JSON Object that contains a JSONArray with a key. This is how I declare it:

```
JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject myObj = new JSONObject();
myObj.put("MYKEY", myList);
```

I am trying to replace the name of "MYKEY" to "MYNEWKEY", and i tried using

```
myObj.put("MYNEWKEY",myObj.get("MYKEY");
myObj.remove("MYKEY");
```

but this only creates another JSONArray with the contents of "MYKEY" to "MYNEWKEY".

What I want to achieve is the have the same JSONArray content, with the new key "MYNEWKEY".

Anybody has any idea what i have done wrong ?

I am using these libraries:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

Comment: Which JSON library are you using? There more than one library with `JSONObject` / `JSONArray` class. The name alone does not tell us which library you're using.

Comment: What is `myList` and why is there a `"` after it?

Comment: Why can't you remove the `"MYKEY"` after inserting the `"MYNEWKEY"`? You bring you the same result as renaming.

Comment: @czdepski I tried removing "MYKEY" after inserting the new key, but when when i run my code, nothing happens.

Comment: @Andreas updated my post to include the libraries i am using.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"? Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @AndreasThe line of code where I do myObj.remove("MYKEY") does not run. This line of code was not executed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [`remove("OLD_KEY")`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#remove-java.lang.String-) to remove value and then add this under new key

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. I tried doing myObj.remove("MYKEY") and the line of code does not run.

Comment: @purplewind What does "line of code does not run" mean? It throws exception?

Comment: No exception. When I log myObj, nothing appears in the log so i assumed the line of code was not executed.

Comment: For this kind of  of queestion use debugger

Answer (score 0):

As already [answered by Konstantin Pribluda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52954011/5221149), you remove the old key by calling [`remove`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#remove-java.lang.String-). Since that returns the removed value, you can use it directly.

Here is an [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) *(Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example)*, tested using `org.json:json:20140107`:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

```
String json = "{" +
               " \"Foo\": \"Bar\"," +
               " \"MYKEY\": [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]" +
              "}";
JSONObject myObj = new JSONObject(json);
System.out.println(myObj);
```

```
myObj.put("MYNEWKEY", myObj.remove("MYKEY"));
System.out.println(myObj);
```

*Output*

```
{"MYKEY":[1,2,3,4],"Foo":"Bar"}
```

```
{"Foo":"Bar","MYNEWKEY":[1,2,3,4]}
```

As you can see, the `MYKEY` property was renamed to `MYNEWKEY`.

Comment: Yes I currently can name the "MYNEWKEY" but i am still getting "MYKEY" in the output. I do not want "MYKEY" to be in my output. Thats the thing

Comment: @purplewind And the code shown here does not have `MYKEY` in the output after the "rename".

Comment: Sadly it does not work on my side. Its okay I will figure this out on my own. Thanks anyway

Comment: Maybe I am using JSONArray mapped with a key in a JSONObject thats why.